# Using jQuery to disable input text box type="file"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to disable a HTML input tag with `type="file"` which I am using to upload images. I am using the Radio options to indicate Yes or No.  If the user clicks no - it should disable the input text box. This is the code I used but I don't know what I have done wrong.

```js
$('#inputattrib').change(function() {
  $('#images').prop('disabled', false);
});
$('#inputattribf').change(function() {
  $('#images').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <p> Indicate Payment Method:</p>
  <input id="inptrue" type="radio" name="pmethod" value="Yes">Yes
  <input id="inpfalse" type="radio" name="pmethod" value="No">No
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="file">Upload your Payment Evidence: <i>for Bank Deposit only</i></label>
  <input id="images" type="text" name="file" class="form-first-name form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: its type is not file `<input id="images" type="text"`

Comment: what is `#inputattrib`?

Comment: @Mohammad You have totally destructed the question dude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **main problem** is with the `type` attribute of `<script>`. You have `type="javascript/text"` that's what is not allowing it to work.

On a lighter note, you have used `type="text"`. Did you mean, `type="file"`?

Make sure that you have `assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js` in the right position.

Also, there's no elements matching the selector `#inputattrib`. That's the reason it is not working. You need to use the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group" style="">
      <p> Indicate Payment Method:</p>
      <input id ="inptrue" type="radio" name="pmethod" value="Yes">Yes<br />
      <input id="inpfalse" type="radio" name="pmethod" value="No">No;
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="file">Upload your Payment Evidence: <i>for Bank Deposit only</i></label>
      <input id="images" type="text" name="file" class="form-first-name form-control" />
    </div>  
    <script>
   $('#inptrue').click(function() {
      $('#images').prop('disabled', false);
    });
    $('#inpfalse').click(function() {
      $('#images').prop('disabled', true);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Working Output: http://output.jsbin.com/vijinukape**

As per the OP, the working code is:

```
$('[name="pmethod"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "Yes")
    $('#images').removeAttr('disabled');
  else
    $('#images').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: Hey good one: Its working now perfectly now.  Here is the code that helped me answered by someone here:  Thanks a great deal for solving my problem:  HERE IS THE CODE YOU SENT THAT WORKED:  $('[name="pmethod"]').change(function() {
  if($(this).val()==="Yes")
    $('#images').removeAttr('disabled');
  else
    $('#images').attr('disabled','disabled');
});

Comment: @user3418506 Using `prop` is better, as you have used already.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I guess that the OP is using old jQuery. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22051/)**.

Your code is correct you have just to remove the `type` from script tag or change it to `type="text/javascript"` instead.

And it will be better if you assign the event by name one time and use value as condition instead of adding two events :

```
$('[name="pmethod"]').change(function() {
    if($(this).val()=="Yes")
       $('#images').removeAttr('disabled');
    else
       $('#images').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('[name="pmethod"]').change(function() {
  if($(this).val()==="Yes")
    $('#images').removeAttr('disabled');
  else
    $('#images').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group" style="">
  <p> Indicate Payment Method:</p>
  <input id ="inptrue" type="radio" name="pmethod" value="Yes">Yes<b>
  <input id="inpfalse" type="radio" name="pmethod" value="No">No;                       
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Upload your Payment Evidence: <i>for Bank Deposit only</i></label>
    <input id="images" type="text" name="file" class="form-first-name form-control">
  </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to tell the type attribute, which is what is one of the main problem, JavaScript didn't execute.